# Enumerating theorems with numbers and letters

Tags: amsthm

I want to have my theorem environments to enumerate using both numbers and letters.  Right now I have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\begin{theorem}
    This enumerates as ``1.1." but I want ``1.1.a."
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
    Then this one would be ``1.1.b"
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

I know I can use

```
\renewcommand*{\thetheorem}{\alph{theorem}}
```

to enumerate with letters but I'm not sure how to proceed in applying that to this situation.

Comment: The other `1` refer to what?

Comment: @Bernard a subsection

Comment: And if there's a section  but no subsection yet when the theorem is enunciated?

Comment: so it I change it to `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]` I can get 1.1.1, but how would I get the lettering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prefix the `section` *and* `subsection` numbers to the theorem "number" (here: lowercase letter), you need to replace `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]` with `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} % for '\newtheorem' macro
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\renewcommand\thetheorem{\thesubsection.\alph{theorem}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\begin{theorem}
    I want ``1.1.a.'' -- check!
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
    This one should be ``1.1.b.'' -- check!
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I start a new subsection afterwards, the letter enumeration does not reset.  So, after `setcounter{subsection}{2}`, the next theorem is numbered 1.2.c rather than resetting to 1.2.a

Comment: @CrimsonRain - `\setcounter{subsection}{2}` will definitely *not* give you the desired result -- but that's not because of any mistake in the code I posted. In fact, `\setcounter{subsection}{2}`, `\stepcounter{subsection}`, and `\addtocounter{subsection}{1}` will all fail to increment the `theorem` "slave counter". What you need to do is execute `\refstepcounter{subsection}` -- or, probably more simply, issue a `\subsection{...}` instruction.